# about do-release-upgrade on ubuntu server lts

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, upgrade

i'm working on a cloud server running `Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS` and i was wondering to know what happen if i do a `do-release-upgrade` to the new stable version `Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS`.

Since i'm running an `NGINX` server with `php-5.3`, `php-fpm` and `MYSQL`, my question is: **all this packages were automatically updated to the latest stable release compatible with the new Ubuntu version? or i will have problems? reinstall etc...**

hope this make sense and find an answer... thanks in advance for any response.

***PS:*** i'm scared about losing all my nginx config as well as my database...

Comment: `i'm scared about losing all my nginx config as well as my database` backup before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you stay with stock Ubuntu packages, an upgrade usually works quite well, but the more you modify your system with hand-installed software or 3rd party repos like PPAs, the more likely it is that you will run into serious difficulties while upgrading.

The issues you describe in your first, now deleted, question would make it somewhat likely that you will run into major problems when upgrading and quite frankly, I would consider starting again from scratch with Ubuntu 16.04 at this point.

Comment: nice to see you read my deleted question. ;-) btw, I finally understood how the repositories thing works, (though i'm pretty new to the linux world, also consider i'm doing all via ssh for the first time) and probably all that problems i had, were caused by confilct between a previous "stock" install of nginx, php, mysql and a new ppa install. fortunately after some good reading i found a way to remove entirely both ppa and php and reinstall the default php via apt-get and now everyhting works fine. a problem remain now, how to install a new version of php without using ppa..!